# An exception occured while fetching content. The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I'm getting errors all the time when i'm trying reindex all my contents.

Error message:

```
2014-06-12 08:12:18,851 ERROR [10] EPiServer.Find.Cms.ContentIndexer.ReIndex - An exception occured while fetching content. The given key was not present in the dictionary.. If you are using PageTypeBuilder please make sure that you are using >= 1.3.1.
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at EPiServer.DataAccess.ContentListDB.ReadPageList(DbCommand cmd)
   at EPiServer.DataAccess.ContentListDB.<>c__DisplayClass19.<LoadSpecificContentInstances>b__18()
   at EPiServer.Data.Providers.SqlDatabaseHandler.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at EPiServer.Data.Providers.SqlDeadlockRetryPolicy.Execute[TResult](Boolean isInTransaction, Func`1 method)
   at EPiServer.Data.Providers.SqlDatabaseHandler.Execute[TResult](Func`1 action)
   at EPiServer.DataAccess.ContentListDB.LoadSpecificContentInstances(Int32[] contentLinks, Int32 languageBranchID)
   at EPiServer.DataAbstraction.ContentStore.LoadSpecificContentInstances(Int32[] contentLinks, Int32 languageBranchID)
   at EPiServer.DefaultContentProvider.LoadContents(IList`1 contentReferences, ILanguageSelector selector)
   at EPiServer.Core.ContentProvider.GetScatteredContents(IList`1 contentLinks, ILanguageSelector selector)
   at EPiServer.DataFactory.GetItems(IEnumerable`1 contentLinks, ILanguageSelector selector)
   at EPiServer.Find.Cms.ContentIndexer.ReIndex(Action`1 statusAction, Func`1 isStopped)
```

I'm not using "PageTypeBuilder"

Episerver 7, Episerver Find 7.0.586.16

If somebody knows how can I fix it please answer.

Comment: Any idea what pages are causing this problem?

Comment: You'd be better off posting this issue on http://world.episerver.com/, since that has a lot more visibility by the EPiServer team.